# Rules adding in yii2/admin

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I created a Rule using yii2/admin.I attach the rule to Roles.But when I run the page it shows

> Forbidden (#403) You are not allowed to perform this action.

Here I show the step That i had done.

[Giving Rule To Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzJlF.jpg)

Here I login with the user with The permission

[When Selecting the Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v98Rz.jpg)

My AuthorRule.php controller

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;
use yii\rbac\Rule;

class AuthorRule extends Rule
{
public $name = 'contactadmin';
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
return isset($params['post']) ?$params['post']->createdBy 
== $user  : false;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: plz help me to do this task

Comment: [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#using-rules] . how can we implement this using yii2/admin.